# Why google map api and google map lat long differ

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google map api in my project and my code for calling google api was

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', intilize);
     function intilize() {
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("txtautocomplete"));

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {

           var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
           var location = "Address: " + place.formatted_address + "<br/>";
           location += "Latitude: " + place.geometry.location.lat() + "<br/>";
           location += "Longitude: " + place.geometry.location.lng();
           document.getElementById('lblresult').innerHTML = autocomplete.getPlace();
        });

     }
```

that code return me lat long for this address "Basic English School, Old City Rampuriya, Bikaner, Rajasthan 334001, India" was 
**28.0142902
73.2970368**

But when i checked this address on google map then the lat long was
**28.014326,73.2948053,**
So why the both service returning differ results.

Comment: the building on google maps at **28.0142902,73.2970368** is the Basic English School ... **28.014326,73.2948053** on google maps is about 200metres west ... it's actually half way between **Basic English School, Old City Rampuriya, Bikaner, Rajasthan 334001, India** and something that is labelled **Basic English Snr Sec** at **28.016673,73.2896248**

Comment: i didn't get your point.. @JaromandaX. will you please give the code by which i will get exact same value as like google map in google api

Comment: my point is, when I look up that "school" on google maps, I get the same coordinates as you get using your code ... the coordinates YOU get on google maps is 200m to the west of that "school" if you enter it into google maps ... on yet another site, those two coordinates were about 100m south (and 100m east/west) of that "school" - I believe google maps has a margin of error of about 200 metres so people can't use it to guide missiles or something (tongue in cheek)